# Is it possible to use other .resw files for localization other than Resources.resw in UWP?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I'm building an app which I'd like to localize to english and my native language, and it will have many, many strings to localize. Implementation of localization is not a problem, my problem is organization. Is it possible to use different files, like "Informations.resw","Recipes.resw", "UI.resw" and so on to organize things better? If yes, how can I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it possible to use different files, like "Informations.resw", "Recipes.resw", "UI.resw" and so on to organize things better? If yes, how can I do it?

Yes, this is possible. To achieve what you want, you can add multiple resource files in ***Strings*** folder per language like the following:
[image]

And then you can refer to the resources in XAML like:

```
<TextBlock x:Uid="/UI/Greeting" />
```

Or in code like:

```
var resourceLoader = Windows.ApplicationModel.Resources.ResourceLoader.GetForCurrentView("Informations");
var str = resourceLoader.GetString("XXInfo");
```

For more information, please see [How to load string resources](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh965323.aspx).